# Which side has more?

Tags: code-golf

The challenge is to golf a program when given a string composed of any number of asterisks, then a comma, than any number of asterisks, say which side has more.

The asterisk-strings can be empty.

## Output

`0` for ties.

`1` for the left.

`2` for the right.

## Examples

Input: `***,****` Output: `2`

Input: `***,` Output: `1`

Input: `***,***` Output: `0`

Input: `,` Output: `0`

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer wins.

Comment: It seems this would be improved by loosening the output format—for example, allowing -1, 0, and 1 for the three possibilities, or really any three consistent outputs.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is Ok at this stage (already 25 answers).  Some of the existing answers (including my own) already made some effort to adhere to the originally-specified output format.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Alright, I will remove this option,

Answer (score 19):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 25 bytes

```python
lambda s:cmp(s[::-1],s)%3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHYKjm3QKM42spK1zBWp1hT1fh/Wn6RQo5CZp5CUWJeeqqGqaYVlwJIrAhNTCGxuDi1qEQhTUNdS11BC6hHW0FdRx1EgvlFmgq2tgrRBjoKhjoKRrHRIItydIDCsf8B)

Answer (score 8):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), <s>60</s> <s>64</s> 28 bytes

```
/*,*/,//,*/2//*,/1//,/0//*//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/X19LR0tfR18fSBrpAzn6hkC2vgGQqa//X0sLKAsC/wE)

Found out most of my program was unnecessary, -32 bytes.

I made this program when I was learning the language, and decided to post it as a question.

Comment: Very cool language for the problem

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Â.S(3%
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cJNesIax6v//WlpaOkAMAA)**

#### How?

Note that `','` is greater than `'*'`.

```
Â.S(3%
Â      - input, reversed(input) (say a, b)
 .S    - compare: 1 if a > b; -1 if a < b; 0 if a = b
   (   - negate
    3  - push three
     % - modulo
```

Comment: Nice approach!!

Comment: @LuisMendo Did you see dingledooper's Python answer?

Comment: @Memberfor3months I hadn't seen it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>65</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>54</s></sup> 47 bytes

Saved a 10 bytes thanks to [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper)!!!
Saved a byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!
Saved 7 bytes thank to [l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2)!!!

```c
f(c){c=strlen(c)-strspn(c,"*")*2;c=c>1?2:c!=1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVDBbsMgDL33KzxLlYASLcm0Q8foDtO@osmhomRL1KUR5IAW5dszF5GtSIZn/J4fxmSfxixLwwyfjPaju9iecEbID4QkCuSiVEabQ/FWvpgHXah5@T61PeMwbYCW@To5Ae5Yg4YJq/BRVmH/TvGMEu7zJ5zVnWK0fvRJJYSQFALJUMi4xwu84aRq@xFsGGwY7TnKYCplIXOZJ0JzdcBurI6KuaLjFXz7Y68Ni178MWXRnyvY7bp1iNUgkDTRj13N1V9xcFRuGFa49RVCdoDtGQj2NORKlxAkfQT10P8v7eq1zbyZl18)

Comment: `f(c){c=strlen(c)-strspn(c,"*")*2;c=c>1?2:c!=1;}` if high address not used

Comment: @l4m2 Works on TIO, so I guess it's allowed - thanks! :D

Answer (score 4):

## Gema, 20 characters

```
*,*=@cmps{*;*;2;0;1}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ echo -n '***,****' | gema '*,*=@cmps{*;*;2;0;1}'
2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/X0tHy9YhObeguFrLWsvayNrA2rAWKKoFFAcCAA) / [Try all test cases online!](https://tio.run/##lZA9T8MwEIbn@FccVui1VqN8rJaldmBgQmINEUodl1ZtE8t2JaTQ3x7sBEoHGBh89/ruPd1jb2q7Gxolj7VRkKzBKeteZW2VmJOoRMbY0h@GlcACvyvhluNNPxSysbD8kgtCtNm3bgv4AfdJnln4JRc@vrQI@Njqs/P5WdnzMYiHd62kU42XTwckZNsZ2AeTj0Dj/u4KWq6qC@XQdCQy47Sg8RyU3HWQBOs4Rf22tNMufVOnOrVGjgJw8PhiJU/a9owzXvCM55cBYUEJif7xgOsaGk8QQfU/jFPbg0KAK8sbnxB/WasKZrPpJeETAlTTtWr4BA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Standard utilities, 28 bytes

```bash
dc<<<1`tr *, 1d`1-dd*v/3+3%p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PyXZxsbGMKGkSEFLR8EwJcFQNyVFq0zfWNtYteD/fy0tLR0g1gIA)

Answer (score 4):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) -E, 30 bytes

```
s/(.*),\1/0/;s/.+0/1/;s/0.+/2/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1hfQ09LUyfGUN9A37pYX0/bQN8QxDDQ09Y30v//XwsEdID4X35BSWZ@XvF/XVcA)

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{2/c<|c:#'","\x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7n2ZVbaSfbFOTbKWsrqSjFFNR@z9NXUNJS0tLB4i1lKzBTCgFFjBUBqrT/P8fAA)

**Explanation:**

```
{2/c<|c:#'","\x} / the solution               -> e.g. 1         e.g. 2     e.g. 3
{             x} / lambda taking implicit 'x' -> "***,****"     "***,"     "***,***"
          ","\   / split string on comma      -> ("***";"****") ("***";"") ("***";"***")
        #'       / count length of each       -> 3 4            3 0        3 3
      c:         / store as c                 -> 3 4 (noop)     3 0        3 3
     |           / reverse it                 -> 4 3            0 3        3 3
   c<            / is c less than this?       -> 1 0            0 1        0 0
 2/              / convert from base 2        -> 2              1          0
```

**Extra:**

- **13 bytes** if it doesn't need to be a function `2/c<|c:#'","\`

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>7</s>  6 bytes

```
,ṚMḄ2c
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of characters which yields an integer in \$[0,2]\$.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/n4c5Zvg93tBgl////X11LS0sHiNUB)**

#### How?

Note that `','` is greater than `'*'`.

```
,ṚMḄ2c - Main Link: s                     e.g.:  "*,"          ",*"          ","
 Ṛ     - reverse (s)                             ",*"          "*,"          ","
,      - pair (s) with (that)                    ["*,",",*"]   [",*","*,"]   [",",","]
  M    - indices of maximal values               [2]           [1]           [1,2]
   Ḅ   - convert from base 2, say x              2             1             4
    2  - two                                     2             2             2
     c - (2) choose (x) - i.e. binomial(2,x)     1             2             0
       - implicit print (a list with a single element prints the element)
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>26</s>  25 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @tsh*

Taking advantage of the looser output rules: this versions returns `0` for ties, `undefined` for left or `*` for right.

```javascript
s=>(s+0)[s.search`,`*2+1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/Y1k6jWNtAM7pYrzg1sSg5I0EnQctI2zD2f3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGkpaWlg4QaylpanJhkcIhjF0DSPV/AA)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 31 bytes

[Returns a Boolean value](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9067/58563) instead of **0** / **1**.

```javascript
s=>([a,b]=s.split`,`,a<b?2:a>b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/Y1k4jOlEnKda2WK@4ICezJEEnQSfRJsneyCrRLknzf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66hnaahpKWlpYOEGspaWpyYZPDJY5DC0j9fwA)

Comment: @Shaggy Do you mean other than the one I'm linking to in my answer?

Comment: Christ! I really _can't_ function without caffeine, can I?! :\

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-pl`, 21 bytes

```perl
/,/;$_=$`cmp$';s;-1;2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19fR99aJd5WJSE5t0BF3brYWtfQ2uj/fy0tLR0g1uICMbigPC6df/kFJZn5ecX/dQtyAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>20</s> <s>19</s> 13 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SBCS)</sup>

Whooping -6 thanks to @Bubbler.

```apl
(⊃3|⍒-⍋)⊂,⊂∘⌽
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG9qZr7Co7YJCgZc1cY1Gnb6jzpmPOqdpAtldGs@6t2q8ahnL5DSrAUpedTVrAFSgCmnAZQCymOTQ5WqRpb7j6atq0kHiEGW9@z9nwZ22qPePqCaQ@uNH7VNBDo4OMgZSIZ4eAYD5dW1tLR0gFhLnQvKgTOggjrqOuoA) This should be golfable as there are some things I am repeating there but I am not sure how to do it yet.

### [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 19  bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
{3|×1+(2×⍵⍳',')-≢⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG9qZr7Co7YJCgb/q41rDk831NYwOjz9Ue/WR72b1XXUNXUfdS4C8mr/p4FVPerte9TV/Kh3zaPeLYfWGz9qmwg0ITjIGUiGeHgGA1Wpa2lp6QCxljoXlANnQAV1gOYCAA)

Comment: [13 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG9qZr7Co7YJCgZc1cY1Gnb6jzpmPOqdpAtldGs@6t2q8ahnL5DSrAUpedTVrAFSgCmnAZQCymOTQ5WqRpb7j6atq0kHiEGW9@z9nwZ22qPePqCaQ@uNH7VNBDo4OMgZSIZ4eAYD5dW1tLR0gFhLnQvKgTOggjrqOuoA) using your second answer as the starting point.

Comment: @Bubbler thanks for the step by step!

Comment: I would be interested in understanding how my answer isn't helpful and the reason it got downvoted :)

Comment: (1 of 2) 05AB1E, Jelly, Japt and (2 of 2) APL answers downvoted - I imagine someone does not think we're counting bytes, (only ones missing would be Charcoal and Stax, maybe they didn't go to page 2).

Comment: @JonathanAllan that is weird, I even link the SBCS wiki page so people can rest assured I'm really counting bytes :/ these downvote floods always confuse me

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 9 bytes

```apl
(⊥⍋|⍒)⊢⍮⌽
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/X@NR19JHvd01j3onaT7qWvSod92jnr3/0xQetU1QeNTb96ir@dB640dtEx/1TQ0OcgaSIR6ewUB5dS0tLR0g1lLngnLgDKigjrqOOgA)

#### How it works

```apl
(⊥⍋|⍒)⊢⍮⌽  ⍝ left '*,' | right ',*' | equal ','
      ⊢⍮⌽  ⍝ Length-2 nested vector of self and reverse
  ⍋        ⍝ Grade up; order of indices to make it ascending-sorted
           ⍝ 1 2       | 2 1        | 1 2
    ⍒      ⍝ Grade down; order of indices to make it descending-sorted
           ⍝ 2 1       | 1 2        | 1 2
   |       ⍝ Right modulo left
           ⍝ 0 1       | 1 0        | 0 0
 ⊥         ⍝ From base 2 to integer
           ⍝ 1         | 2          | 0
```

Comment: How many bytes if you port my [oK](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206156/69200) answer?

Comment: @streetster APL doesn't have a built-in for "split at `','`".

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) -nl, 18 bytes

```ruby
~/,/;p ($`<=>$')%3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v05fR9@6QEFDJcHG1k5FXVPV@P9/LS0tHSDm0uHSgjK1uCAMLqgMlATxgGyQKJeO1r/8gpLM/Lzi/7p5OQA)

Takes input from STDIN. Compares the regex match groups `` $` `` and `$'`, which are set equal to everything on the left and right of the comma, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>9</s> 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

[Returns `true/false` instead of `1/0`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9067/58563)

```
>Ô?2:U<Ô

>Ô?2:U<Ô     :Implicit input of string U
>            :Greater than
 Ô           :  U reversed
  ?          :If true
   2         :  Literal 2
    :        :Else
     U<Ô     :  U less than U reversed?
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=PtQ/MjpVPNQ&footer=wlU&input=IioqKioqLCoqKioqIg)

## Original, 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

5 bytes just to handle the I/O requirements :\

```
q, mÊrÎu3
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=cSwgbcpyznUz&input=IioqKioqKiwqKioqKiI)

```
q, mÊrÎu3     :Implicit input of string
q,            :Split on ","
   m          :Map
    Ê         :  Length
     r        :Reduce by
      Î       :  Sign of difference
       u3     :Positive modulo 3
```

If we could take a space delimited string as input then -2 bytes:

```
¸mÊrÎu3
```

If we could take an array as input then -1 more byte:

```
mÊrÎu3
```

And, if we could use any 3 distinct values for the output then -2 more bytes:

```
mÊrÎ
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 51 bytes

Mod3 doesn't work in Io. Too bad.

```
method(x,I := -x compare(x reverse);if(I== -1,2,I))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z/n6ZgZasQ8z83tSQjP0WjQscTxNetUEjOzy1ILErVqFAoSi1LLSpO1bTOTNPwtAVKGuoY6Xhqav5P01DS0tLSAWItJU2FgqLMvJKcPC6oKKYIhjIkNf8B)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 83 bytes

```c
x;f(char*z){char*Z,*W;for(Z=z;44-*Z++;);for(W=Z;*W++;)Z--;x=!!x*((x=z-Z+1)<0?1:2);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxLCsIwEIav0gYKk0kGrHTlGDxGIXRTItEurBKlhBbPHpuAi@F/MZ@jm3MpRfbg7mPAVW5Frcae/TOANSt3HaFVimVpemMZ@xwtEUdT1xEBolnJqlaeD5f2dJT8TdP8qR7jNEM2ThcsLnLLDF6U0kSO5SvsswfhYRDNexCyMlVzHWahcdEe9ofMSoio98Ni/inpHw)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 58 bytes

- Thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat) for this shorter version.

```c
f(z,Z)long z,Z;{Z-=strlen(Z=index(z,44))+z-1;z=Z<0?2:!!Z;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzBCoMwEER/JQaE3XUDbfHUNPQ/ghdJjRVsLFGkKP32NC30MPCGx4xTvXMpedjY4jiFXmTQu1VmXuLYBbBmCLfulX1dI1abOurN2MvhejoXhdXvNIRFPNohwBccu3sbiVbc/RRBr1XFSjmNz5i1B@mhkeXcSBRGlLcmSKaVPeQB5q9ERJxDP/i3xB8)

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 57 bytes

```
-[>>,<--[>-<++++++]>-]<+[<<,]>[<-->+[<+>+]]-[<+>-----]<-.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYnBCYBAEAML2osVhDSy5KGCIIIPwfrXPeczA7M963kf735VIaVBtMD4sWBGksPKPuoOhY1pTEwsVR8)

It spreads `*` on the tape and checks if the second branch went past the first.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>15</s> 13 bytes

```
(.*),\1$

\*+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8F9DT0tTJ8ZQhYsrRkv7/38tLS0dLTDggjHBDCgPJsilAwA)

If the right-hand-side has an equal or less number of `*`'s, then those `*`'s are removed from both sides, along with the `,`.

Then the number of runs of `*`'s are counted.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 10, <s>74</s> <s>51</s> 50 bytes

```java
s->(Long.signum(s.indexOf(44)*2-s.length()+1)+3)%3
```

-24 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jY7LCsIwEEX3/YpBEJLUBnzsin6Bj4VLcRHTWFPTqTipKNJvr/G1bmcxzONy7i3UTSVFdm61U0SwUhafEYBFb65HpQ2s3yuAqzAHzbb@asNAPA3XJgqNvPJWwxoQ5i0lC7YMSkk2x7pkJC1m5r45stmMi0lC0hnM/YnxeMzjKR9O2/QNudQHFyA/1q2yGZQhyc9utwfFvzG2D/KmlFXt5SW8vEOGUrOBEGIkPjXgn2zd0l7CnrS@pp26bsPRH9JETfsC)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->{                          // Method with String parameter and long return-type
  Math.signum(                //  Take the signum of:
   s.indexOf(44)              //   The index of ',' (codepoint 44)
   *2                         //   multiplied by 2
   -s.length()                //   Subtract the entire length of the input
   +1                         //   And add 1
  +3)                         //  Then increase that result by 3
  %3                          //  And take modulo-3 on it
```

Comment: [51 bytes if `double` as result is accepted](https://tio.run/##jY7NCsIwEITvfYqlICSxDahH0TdQDx7FQ0xjTW234m5FkT57jX/ndg8LOzt8M4W5mbTIzp0tDRGsjMdnBOCR3fVorIP1@wTI6uZQOrBiy1ePOZCcB72NwiI27C2sAWHRUboUK8MnTT7HphKkPWbuvjmKOImlmqakS4c5n4QcT@R4Jkezbv6mXAI/UH6wW@0zqEKZX95uD0Z@m2wfxK7SdcP6El5cokBtRayUStRnYvkp128dZBxIGxra6@sPTP6QNmq7Fw)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Oh, nice approach. Maybe you should post it as a separated answer, since it's completely different than what I currently have. :)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Ah ok, from that 72 byter to your 51 byter makes indeed sense. If you don't want to post it, I will edit. Thanks! :)

Comment: F.Y.I. I just noticed that `Long.signum` exists. It might be better than `Math.signum` so that there's not this trailing `.0`.

Comment: A further byte can be saved by replacing `","` with `44` (which is the codepoint for the comma).

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, <s>64</s> <s>63</s> 62 bytes

```
=IF(LEN(A1)+1=2*FIND(",",A1),0,IF(LEN(A1)<2*FIND(",",A1),1,2))
```

-1 byte thanks to Dominic van Essen
-1 byre thanks to Chronocidal

Comment: 63 bytes by using ```>=```: ```=IF(LEN(A1)+1=2*FIND(",",A1),0,IF(LEN(A1)>=2*FIND(",",A1),2,1))```

Comment: Can't you save another byte by changing `>=` to `<`, and swapping the `2` and the `1`? (i.e. inverting the Logical Condition)

Comment: A few bytes can be saved by subtracting from 2 rather than using conditionals:. =2-(find(",",A1)>Len(a1)/2)-(find(",",A1)*2=Len(A1)+1)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) -n, <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```ruby
p (~/,/*2<=>~/.$/)%3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BBo05fR1/LyMbWrk5fT0VfU9X4/38tLS0dIObS4dKCMrW4IAwuqAyUBPGAbJAol47Wv/yCksz8vOL/unkA)

Comment: That's cool! I think it's its own answer.

Comment: [Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205816/92901) :)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>19</s></sup> 18 bytes

```
3|i.&','*@--:@<:@#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/jWsy9dTUddS1HHR1rRxsrByU/2v@T1NQ19LS0gFidS44G4kJ5eioAwA)

#### How it works

```
3|i.&','*@--:@<:@#
           -:@<:@# halved (length-1) of list
                   (where , would be in a balanced list)
  i.&','           position of the ,
        *@-        signum'd difference between both
3|                 mod 3
```

### Alternative version, 19 bytes

This inserts `-` and `+` between the bit mask of the string: `**,* -> 1 1 0 1 -> 1 + (1 + (0 - 1)))` to get the difference between both sides. Then both signum and mod 3 like other solutions.

```
3|[:*'*'-`+@.[/@:=]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/jWuirbTUtdR1E7Qd9KL1HaxsY/9r/k9TUNfS0tIBYnUuOBuJCeXoqAMA)

#### How it works

```
3|[:*'*'-`+@.[/@:=]
     '*'         =] '***,*' -> 1 1 1 0 1
        -`+@.[      a function that chooses - or + based on the left argument
              /@:   puts this function inbetween: 1+(1+(1+(0-1))) = 2
  [:*               signum: 2 -> 1
3|                  mod 3
```

Comment: [14 bytes](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/jTSU9WKsavStNGOta/T@a/5PU1DX0tLSAWJ1LjgbwUQS1ELlQHg66lwA) by porting [my APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205764/78410).

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 31 bytes

```
2>1~:1+v
p^_"$"2 0
.@^-","_$2\-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/38jOsM7KULuMqyAuXklFyUjBgEvPIU5XSUcpXsUoRvf/fy0tLR0gBgA)

After initially pushing `2` to the stack, we push `1` for every `*` we encounter. After finding the `,`, we start popping them instead. When we run out of input we subtract the top of the stack from 2, resulting in the correct output values.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 56 <strike>60</strike> bytes

-4 bytes thanks to math junkie

A third approach to this in python.

```python
def f(x):a,b=x.split(',');return(1,0,2)[((a<b)-(a>b))+1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFNo0LTKlEnybZCr7ggJ7NEQ11HXdO6KLWktChPw1DHQMdIM1pDI9EmSVNXI9EuSVNT2zD2f0FRZl6JRpqGupaWlo6WlrqmJhdCCEMAQwRThZYOqgIQ7z8A)

Comment: You can remove some unnecessary whitespace: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PyU1TSFNo0LTKlEnybZCr7ggJ7NEQ11HXdO6KLWktChPw1DHQMdIM1pDI9EmSVNXI9EuSVNT2zD2f0FRZl6JRpqGupaWlo6WlrqmJhdCCEMAQwRThZYOqgIQ7z8A "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>55</s> <s>51</s> 47 bytes

```php
fn($s)=>(3+(($a=explode(',',$s))[0]<=>$a[1]))%3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSZvs/LU9DpVjT1k7DWFtDQyXRNrWiICc/JVVDXUddByihGW0Qa2Nrp5IYbRirqalq/N@aiys1OSNfQSVNQ0lLS0sHiLWUNPWUYvKUrFFlsItiVQ5X@x8A)

This is the best I have so far.. Gosh, longer than Java and C :O

EDIT: saved 4 bytes using value of `$v`, now shorter than C!

EDIT2: thanks a lot to 640KB for finding the finely elegant way to have the right numbers! -4 bytes

Much shorter with only distinct values instead of fixed numbers requirement:

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 39 bytes

```php
fn($s)=>($a=explode(',',$s))[0]<=>$a[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSZvs/LU9DpVjT1k5DJdE2taIgJz8lVUNdR10HKKgZbRBrY2unkhhtGPvfmosrNTkjX0ElTUNJS0tLB4i1lDT1lGLylKxRZbCLYlUOV/sfAA)

Comment: For fun, here's what I came up with before I saw yours - the same size actually! https://tio.run/##XY49C8IwEIbn5lccJZIPI9p2s02dBAeh3VWklIQMYkOTTuJvj0EKfgw33PM@x73W2FDtrLEIYa@cdyDhhBLCORdxOBGQrNfQTN5Ofgv5HP3h7HNBxHewiUGUk192KeM3LYO@U@yYrGmxpM6PdnBxjzphPK9kHdFNvZVVxtiiCCXSw6i63tC5a@cAewYPBKB6M0CK/dmnArCOBhPQHtrrvjmW6Ble

Answer (score 2):

### Excel,  <s>*44*</s>  40 Bytes

```
=MOD(3-SIGN(1+LEN(A1)-2*FIND(",",A1)),3)
```

Finds the difference between Total Length + 1 and twice the position of the comma (Negative: Left; Zero: Tie; Positive: Right), use `SIGN` to convert these into `-1`, `0` and `1`.  Then subtract this from 3 to give `4`/`0`/`2`, and take the Modulo Base 3 (`1`, `0`, `2`)

**Old version: 44 Bytes**

```
=MID(102,2+SIGN(1+LEN(A1)-2*FIND(",",A1)),1)
```

Finds the difference between Total Length + 1 and twice the position of the comma (Negative: Left; Zero: Tie; Positive: Right), use `SIGN` to convert these into `-1`, `0` and `1`, add 2 (`1`, `2`, `3`), and then use `MID` to take the first, second or third digit from `102`, respectively.

(Using `MID` saved 3 bytes over using `CHOOSE`)

I also experimented with a more maths-based approach (Multiply the Sign by 1.5, round it in the Positive direction with `CEILING`, then take the Absolute value), but that was 51 bytes instead.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) - 67 bytes

This is a complete program and can be compiled with gcc. Input is the first command line argument and output is the exit status.

```
main(u,v)int**v;{u=strlen(*++v)-strspn(*v,"*")*2;exit(u>1?2:u!=1);}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) `-F,`, <s>24</s> <s>22</s> 20+3 = 23 bytes

```
$0=$2>$1?2:($1>$2)""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fxcBWxchOxdDeyEpDxdBOxUhTSen/fx0uLR0tLi0woaOl9S@/oCQzP6/4v66bDgA)

*Edit: amazingly, golfing-away 2 bytes has actually made it (a bit) more readable*

Commented version:

```
$0=             # set the line to
    $2>$1 ?     # if $2>$1 (alphabetic comparison)
            2   # 2
    :           # otherwise
      ($1>$2)   # logical: 1 for $1>$2, 0 if not
             "" # append "" to force text output
                # otherwise awk won't print zero

# use default behaviour to print line
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 62 bytes

```python
lambda x:y.index(max(y))+1if len({*(y:=x.split(","))})>1else 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/BisMgEIbP61MMc1KbhqR7KQF772lfoFCy1FAhNRInkFD67Fm1mN0VdHT@b2Z@3UL3wX4e3bh26rL27eP71sLcLKWxNz3zRzvzRYhdbTroteVPyZdGzaV3vSGOBQrxEqda915DtZL25EEBIp6tm6gBKWURtvz4miglDuyPsmVr9p/fhCoLv2wVujPWDSPEcWBsij5bulgUDYOwrsYWcB0mCo4ishGEIgNBCmfpaTSOZ9NZfpcaSzxeM5R9hK8nzI2JiMNwvz9hAV18iRxBqdTqTa8/)

I know that there is a shorter python solution already posted, but `cmp` doesn't exist in python 3. And don't bother trying to use bitwise operators to increment the value... it ends up being the same byte count.

Comment: By unfolding the cmp function you can be much shorter:
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206139/2212

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-nlaF,`, 22 bytes

```ruby
p ($F[0]<=>$F[1]||1)%3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BBQ8Ut2iDWxtYOSBvG1tQYaqoa//@vpaWlA8RaXCAGF5THpcMFov7lF5Rk5ucV/9fNy0l00wEA)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>46</s> 45 bytes

(or [42 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8W2ODkxT0NHXV1HR0ddR13TOiEzLUEjJdoo1i5Fx0gnJdoQyADyNP9raelo/QcA) using TRUE/FALSE instead of 1/0)

```r
d=scan(,'',,,',');`if`(d[2]>d,2,1-!d[2]<d[1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8W2ODkxT0NHXV1HR0ddR13TOiEzLUEjJdoo1i5Fx0jHUFcRxLZJiTaM1fyvpaWj9R8A)

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to Giuseppe*

Comment: You can use `,,` in place of `se=` (forcing R to use the argument order rather than the names) to save a byte. Might also be able to use a `sign(diff(* lengths))%%3` like I've seen in other answers to golf off some bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the ```,,```!  Updated with acknowledgment... (again!)

Comment: ...and you should post the other approach (which is much better than mine and beats it by at least 7 bytes)...

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 48 bytes

```
>~:1+!#v_","-!#v_1+
^ p 0 +$#99 "-"<
+1`_: #<.@.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/367OylBbUbksXklHSRdEG2pzxSkUKBgoaKsoW1oqKOkq2XBpGybEWyko2@g56P3/r6Wlo6UFAA)

Adds one for each character it encounters, until it sees a `,`; in that case, the program self modifies to start subtracting one for each character it encounters. After seeing the end of the string, it checks whether the tally is 0, less than 0, or something else, and prints 0, 2 or 1 accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

## SimpleTemplate, 66 bytes

This was quite fun!

Uses the most basic and naive approach, but the shortest one i can come up with as well.

```
{@ifargv.0 is equalargv.1}0{@elseifargv.0 is lowerargv.1}2{@else}1
```

---

That's quite a mess, lets explore it:

```
{@if argv.0 is equal to argv.1}
    {@echo 0}
{@else if argv.0 is lower than argv.1}
    {@echo 2}
{@else}
    {@echo 1}
{@/}
```

Should be self-explanatory.
A string is considered lower or higher depending on it's length and the characters on it are lower numerically (e.g.: `b > a`).

To turn into a function, all it needs is that the `{@echo}` is converted to `{@return}`.
Due to a bug (version 0.83), you can't return `0`, but you can return `"0"`.

---

You can test this on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/683ec5b3e71cfb4f2bb78267125330b077248ef7

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 38 bytes

```r
sign(-diff(nchar(scan(,'',,,','))))%%3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzgzPU9DNyUzLU0jLzkjsUijODkxT0NHXV1HR0ddR10TCFRVjf9r6Whpaf0HAA)

Credit to [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205772/67312) for the `sep` argument to `scan()`, which I probably use less often than I should.

Ports the mod 3 approach found in a few other answers.

Answer (score 1):

## [Golfscript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/index.html), 22 bytes

```
','/).@).@;@>@@>2 0if+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X11HXV9TzwGIrB3sHBzsjBQMMtO0///XAQA)

```
code   | explanation                      | example
','/   | split input at ',' into list     | "*,**" -> ["*", "**"]
).     | uncons from the right and double | ["*", "**"] -> ["*"] "**" "**"
@).    | put list on tos and do it again  | ["*"] "**" "**" -> "**" "**" [] "*" "*"
@;     | discard empty list               | "**" "**" [] "*" "*" -> "**" "**" "*" "*"
@>     | pull up a "right" and compare    | "**" "**" "*" "*" -> "**" "*" 0
@@     | pull up remaining elements       | "**" "*" 0 -> 0 "**" "*"
>2 0if | compare, if 1 replace with two   | 0 "**" "*" -> 0 2
+      | add the results                  | 0 2 -> 2
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 16 bytes

```
%_._h.+mldcQ","3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/XzVeLz5DTzs3JyU5UElHyfj/fyUtLR0tLS0lAA)

Comment: 12 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X1UvXtctxzc5MEbH@P9/JS0tHS0lAA "Pyth – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 32 bytes

```python
lambda s:((r:=s[::-1])!=s)+(r<s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P802JzE3KSVRodhKQ6PIyrY42spK1zBWU9G2WFNbo8imWPN/QVFmXolGmoa6lpaWjpaWuqYmF0IIQwBDBFOFlg6qAhDvPwA)

It is just one byte shorter than other Python 3.x

```python
lambda s:(s[::-1]!=s)+(s[::-1]<s)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

```
[ÂQ#',¡ć@>,q}0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/@nBToLK6zqGFR9od7HQKaw3@/9cCAR0wqQUA)

A weird program method, I know, but hey, it works! The `ÂQ` part is from [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166431/78850) answer regarding 05AB1E golfing tips

Answer (score 0):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) / MATLAB, <s>41</s> 38 bytes

```matlab
@(x)mod(sign(2*find(x-42)-nnz(x)-1),3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0IzNz9FozgzPU/DSCstMy9Fo0LXxEhTNy@vCiina6ipY6z5P01DXUtLR0td8z8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 18 bytes

```
⊞υθ⊞υ⮌θＩ⁻²↨⮌⌕Ａυ⌈υ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gtDhDo1RHoVDTmgvGDkotSy0qTtUo1AQJFmXmlWg4JxaXaPhm5pUWaxjpKDglAmVhqtwy81Icc3JAGn0TKzJzS3M1SjU1NXUUjICkpvX//1o6Wlr/dctyAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Based on @JonathanAllen's answer. Explanation:

```
⊞υθ⊞υ⮌θ
```

Push the input and its reverse to the predefined empty list.

```
         υ  List of input and reverse
        ⌈   Take the maximum
     ⌕Ａυ    Get the indices of that in the list
    ⮌       Reverse the list of indices
   ↨      ² Convert from base 2
 ⁻²         Subtract from 2
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

When the input equals its reverse, both indices `0, 1` are returned, and `10` equals 2 in base 2, while if the left side has more then the maximum is at index `1`, while if the right side has more then the maximum is at index `0`. Subtracting this from 2 results in the desired value.

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, 43 bytes

```sql
DECLARE @ varchar(max)='*,**'

PRINT(3+sign(charindex(',',@)*2+~len(@)))%3
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <strike>9</strike> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
üJN☺ïS♂
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=814a4e018b530b&i=***,****)

Unpacked:

```
',/E|$3%
```

-2 bytes thanks to recursive

Comment: You can omit `{%m`, as comparisons work on strings too.

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 59 bytes

```powershell
$a,$b=$i.split(',');if($a-gt$b){1}elseif($a-eq$b){0}else{2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmfll@UmpicoaChkqmQmaegkplXUFqiqVD9XyVRRyXJViVTr7ggJ7NEQ11HXdM6M01DJVE3vUQlSbPasDY1pzgVIpJaCBIxAItUG9X@r/2vpaWlA8RaXCAGF5THpQMA)

Answer (score 0):

## [FEU](https://github.com/TryItOnline/feu), <s>30</s> 26 bytes

Saved 4 bytes by using map instead of multiple substitutes

```
m/(\**),\1/0/\*+0/1/0\*+/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0st/f8/V18jRktLUyfGUN9AP0ZL20AfyADS@kb//wMA)

### Explanation

```
m                          # Map mode, execute multiple substitutions
 /(\**),\1/0               # Replaces the balance of the sides with 0
            /\*+0/1        # If there are asterisks on the left of 0, replace with 1
                   /0\*+/2 # If there are asterisks on the right of 0, replace with 2
```