# XOR two strings

Tags: code-golf, string

Given two strings as input, return the result of XORing the code-points of one string against the code points of the other.

For each character in the first input string, take the code-point (e.g. for `A`, this is 65) and XOR the value against the corresponding index in the second string and output the character at the code-point of the result. If one string is longer than the other, you **must return the portion of the string beyond the length of the shorter**, as-is. (Alternatively, you may pad the shorter string with `NUL` bytes, which is equivalent.)

See the following JavaScript code for an example:

```js
const xorStrings = (a, b) => {
  let s = '';

  // use the longer of the two words to calculate the length of the result
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(a.length, b.length); i++) {
    // append the result of the char from the code-point that results from
    // XORing the char codes (or 0 if one string is too short)
    s += String.fromCharCode(
      (a.charCodeAt(i) || 0) ^ (b.charCodeAt(i) || 0)
    );
  }

  return s;
};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVNtT9swEP68/IobX@KsbZp2vKoDxEolPmyCgiYmtYW5idtkMnGwHRo0@O3d2U5pealqXc5@nudedPeXPlAVy6zQrVwkbLmMRa40VEJeaZnlcwWHQGgTpgEcHsE/D4AzDebW93seuu02lIqBThlwkc@ZBDGznl4IWAiZKNACYsrjklNdA1k@1@kKKJkquUapmZBAjHyG8lEPzTf4SXUa3tGK0NCxMJX6K0BEoxHYpGwetChYnmxoriLEKZUwk@LOeVhnqxBZrtGlusYqC1hJ/T6/xOLXZMNRQDDBCLIZiJyBsv2BzNQnQKVC6sDSFTQOwXUvNJp9FOgjn9hXwHaGcX11okkWwNMTRAHcAJl@9GBZQQ/Ns@m3ZLqUOaie94z9H@HNyD9jnIum3wT/WkiefPYnTRfKlOKPq85sXEUULUMb4ZniSfw111AX55c/TtdMxz3@cgQNB6TTOGEGGHW6X7ffAodXw@uhA3KxYDKmyoC3Do59B9pCggH@urgYXPZPrgYOrJnSRhT1PsGrnwHbV4szMXcM8GB/b3fnbXQsZ9@VGG3j6ZoyfbjNhb6FTqcTHXRfBbN2Q@JFJNo8L4EN5eR7/3TwnlMUxWldSdQxuHv1DmeBjm@Bf@K6lOHwA6Ar1JsgNMSFGNA4JWRkNnBiV9Dsp@As5GLuBmq9qm5PvRctneJw4t/s1QPlWUJ1JnIcXv4IFBcFn7BDOFH3ZSYZ@jk8itINe60SSlZwGjPSHt2Mq27UGld7bNKeN4HENh1vlbs/Hlc@NID4kTHx5igHoRYuR9LZDQJvXXGoyikuEml1V7fGIqS3XP4H)

### Test cases

```
Input                         Output

['Hello,', 'World!']          '\x1f\x0a\x1e\x00\x0b\x0d'
['Hello', 'wORLD']            '?*> +'
['abcde', '01234']            'QSQWQ'
['lowercase', "9?'      "]    'UPPERCASE'
['test', '']                  'test'
['12345', '98765']            '\x08\x0a\x04\x02\x00' _not_ 111092
['test', 'test']              '\x00\x00\x00\x00'
['123', 'ABCDE']              'pppDE'
['01', 'qsCDE']               'ABCDE'
['`c345', 'QQ']               '12345'
```

### Rules

- The two input strings will only ever be code-points 0-255.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest solution, in each language, wins.

Comment: Are the two strings limited to ASCII?

Comment: @Bubbler the inputs string will only ever be code-points 0-255.

Comment: You might want to add a few other test cases of varying length besides just `['test', '']`. I see many answers being posted which fail for this test case due to the length difference (or because one of the two is empty maybe).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Done and emboldened (and hopefully added a viable alternative) the detail.

Comment: _Alternatively, padding the shorter string with NUL bytes is equivalent_.
Can you confirm that you mean we can, if we like, assume that the two strings will be of the same length with the originally shorter one padded with NUL characters? Or does this mean that the implementation should do the padding, and that this is equivalent to the requirement to "return the portion of the string beyond the length of the shorter, as-is"?

Comment: @user7761803 I've edited to clarify that I meant it should be padded as part of your answer. Hopefully it's clear now!

Comment: Is code-point `0` required to be valid?  Or can we reserve it as a terminator for implicit-length strings such as C strings?

Comment: Similar to Peter's question: May we input the strings from stdin with a separator character (which would mean that character could not occur in the strings themselves)? This seems like a natural input method, and I think I saw at least one existing answer using it, but it somewhat flies in the face of the strings being code points 0-255.

Comment: That JavaScript implementation doesn't seem correct, since it won't work with code points that encode to surrogate pairs in UTF-16.

Comment: @PererCirdes I certainly wouldn't want to exclude any languages. I think providing it works "in theory" for everything, I'd be happy to preclude NUL bytes from forcibly being accepted as input. I don't know if this flies in the face of any meta posts though, so if it does, please let me know. Would the program theoretically be able to output NUL bytes still?

Comment: @DLosc As per my response to Peter,no think as long as it works ok theory I personally wouldn't want to exclude an entry if it's necessary to have a terminator that doesn't appear in the input.  Same as my question to Peter though, would it preclude it from appearing in the output of it was generated as part of the operation?

Comment: @D.Pardal Oh encodings... Yeah, i imagine there are some interesting potential outputs. I'm not sure I'll get time to look at this today,, but I'll try and create a more bulletproof version. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: In my case, no, output would not be affected.

Comment: "The two input strings will only ever be code-points 0-255." to be actually useful this clause should limit to 0-127, as 0-255 still makes it necessary to parse UTF-8 for languages that work at code-unit level; most of the posted examples ignore the issue, and, fed with e.g. `"è"`/`"è"` in UTF-8, they will output `"\0\0"` instead of just `"\0"`. Or, even better, just drop the whole "code points" thing and rephrase it to work at code unit level, which is ultimately what most languages do (and if one works with codepoints they can still say they are working with UTF-32 code units).

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
O^/Ọ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98/Tv/h7p7///9HqycmJaekqusoqBsYGhmbqMcCAA)

Takes input as a list of the two strings, e.g. `['abcde', '01234']`.

#### How?

```
O    # ord: cast to number (automatically vectorizes)
 ^/  # Reduce by XOR. XOR automatically applies to corresponding elements
         and pads as desired to work if the two strings are different lengths
   Ọ # chr: cast to character (vectorizes once again)
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 4 bytes

```perl6
*~^*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9fCwFREMXffYrhwdQS966/m9jElgfFEh4sWvZuqcvV7hZKvvq6g4Sp0zzM75yZOYlI1tPDFfIhtFPjvjbSVib2rxDC7VD2liXD9lblkjPvDiFUEcj9UcTpEgdCSlXEIuBCRTLI4go@hd6Fh96F@boL3ZnWVivAzNtIvvNoMux/27TRNjpQIMrf7gJBFONmpfpHuVN34RIl1VlEOz8mMmfZ@JrnnjTOxmNn0utOHSITEScU95v0znsONUSrakRZzUa99rdU3998/cSqWib9hbA5qmQDnHNmmQ8)

Raku has a built-in operator for XORing strings, along with string AND, OR and bitshift. This is a Whatever lambda that takes two parameters.

Answer (score 6):

## perl -Mfeature=say,bitwise -nl, 22 bytes

```
$.%2?($;=$_):say$;^.$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19FT9XIXkPF2lYlXtOqOLFSxTpOTyX@/3@P1JycfB2u8PyinBRFLjCPq9w/yMeFKzEpOSWVy8DQyNiEKye/PLUoObE4lcvSXl0BDLhKUotLuLhA0qZclhbmZqb/8gtKMvPziv/r@qalJpaUFqXaAi3SScosKc8sTv2vm5cDAA)

This is way more characters than I first hoped for. If it weren't for those pesky newlines, the 9 character `say<>^.<>` would do.

### How does it work?

For odd input lines, it saves the current line of input (without the trailing newline due to the `-n` and `-l` switches) into `$;`. For even lines, it `xor`s the previous line (`$;`) and the current line (`$_`), and prints it. The `^.` operator does required bitwise string operation.

Comment: I didn't even know about `-Mbitwise`, but I think you can drop it (and the `.`). For single inputs (which is fine IMO), your intended idea should work too: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lPs7Wxu7//5LU4hKuf/kFJZn5ecX/dQtyAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: @DomHastings Yeah, but that relies on having the last line of `STDIN` to not be terminated with a newline, which is kind of icky (and hard to spot when looking at test input). BTW, it's not `-Mbitwise`, but `-Mfeature=bitwise`.

Comment: That's very true, it does! Without the `-Mfeature=bitwise` though, you can avoid the `.` in `^.` for -1!

Comment: Q from someone less-experienced in Perl: do you use ```$;``` as a variable name for a clever reason, or is it just playful obfuscation?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen It has special uses (although I've not used it as intended: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%3b) but it's really useful to use if your script uses `-n`/`-p` as you can use `$` alone, because `-n` wraps your code in `while (<STDIN>) {`...`;}` so you can use the implicit `;`. I'm using a similar trick in this answer https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205760/9365 using `;` as the delimiter for `s///` and relying on the implicit existence. `@;` and `%;` would work too!

Comment: That's very cunning!  But in the case of the particular answer above (where the $ isn't the last character), I take it that using ```$;``` instead of any other more-easy-for-me-to-understand variable name is just down to taste or habit?

Comment: When testing, I was running the program as `perl -M5.032 -nl program.pl < input`. This turns on strict, which prohibits an undeclared `$x` (or any other single letter variable). `$;` however is always a package variable.

Comment: @DomHastings I think `^` instead of `^.` and skipping `-M` won't work if the strings match `[0-9]+` (this is from memory; I haven't checked).

Comment: @Abigail The challenge specifies input is in the range 0-255. So I think you have to account for newlines in the strings. Maybe do it as a subroutine instead of a standalone script (is that still legal here?), something like `pop^.pop`?

Comment: @msh210 It seems to do what's expected in some basic tests without the -Mfeature=bitwise, but there's probably an edge case I'm not aware of... [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lPs7Wxu7/f0MjYxNTLksLczPTf/kFJZn5ecX/dQsA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
80⎕DR≠⌿↑11⎕DR¨⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97b@FwaO@qS5BjzoXPOrZ/6htoqEhmH9oBZACqfjPmcal7pGak5Ovo66gHp5flJOiqM4FFwSKlfsH@bhAhBKTklNSgUIGhkbGJhChnPzy1KLkxGKQsKW9uroCGEDkSlKLS4DCEA5IiylIkYW5mak6AA)

As the OP clarified that the input codepoints will be in the range of 0-255, it is possible to manipulate the underlying data bits directly. Such a string is guaranteed to have data type `80` (8-bit char array), so we convert it to data type `11` (1-bit boolean array) to access the bits, XOR them, and convert back to data type `80`.

```apl
80⎕DR≠⌿↑11⎕DR¨⎕  ⍝ Full program, input: two string literals on a line
        11⎕DR¨⎕  ⍝ Convert each string literal to bit array
       ↑         ⍝ Promote to matrix, padding with 0 as needed
     ≠⌿          ⍝ Bitwise XOR
80⎕DR            ⍝ Convert back to 8-bit char array
```

---

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 17 bytes

```apl
⎕UCS⊥≠⌿⍤2⊤↑⎕UCS¨⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKM97f@jvqmhzsGPupY@6lzwqGf/o94lRo@6ljxqmwiROLQCSINU/udM41L3SM3JyddRV1APzy/KSVFU54ILAsXK/YN8XCBCiUnJKalAIQNDI2MTiFBOfnlqUXJiMUjY0l5dXQEMIHIlqcUlQGEIB6TFFKTIwtzMVB0A)

Well, the task involves converting char to charcode and back AND converting from/to binary, but all current implementations having `⍢` have some quirks so it can't be used here. So here is the very literal implementation of the task.

```apl
⎕UCS⊥≠⌿⍤2⊤↑⎕UCS¨⎕  ⍝ Full program, input: two string literals on one line
           ⎕UCS¨⎕  ⍝ Convert to codepoints
          ↑        ⍝ Promote into a 2-row matrix, padding zeros as necessary
                   ⍝ (doing on characters give spaces which is 0x20, not 0)
         ⊤  ⍝ Convert each number to binary
     ≠⌿⍤2   ⍝ Bitwise XOR
    ⊥       ⍝ Convert the binary back to integers
⎕UCS        ⍝ Convert the integers back to chars
```

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 14 bytes

```
XOR@,:&.(3&u:)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9PT8JAFMTv/RRPDzzR2uwWUGiiCG2NBwJsicEDCZb@OZjGVloD376@7gKpaTeZvD38ZibzVV4bGMOTBQg6MLBI9wbY3uy1/Fh4L7rVMW56nV@rW3ZLfIuSJNURYsB1uk/CK4TLm08NwM2Rx5sj8@lGdBlpRwpRU15pPSy8mVNznrzj22e4I9DfBWEkQcbNXr8JipVYCwKT9BDtAz9X8GiMJxTP4Pty6Xr2ZOUSXER5Ibl/ebVUCWhYVQ5U4PDxYdBspzlDNZH1SWY1E2H7nRZb4JyzkVkrUx9oC2F1qWJpmUxtx23zZFnmVEsYl9xP3uQUqBI0/AzOU4RoBdXWPw)

#### How it works

```
XOR@,:&.(3&u:)
        (3&u:) strings -> code points
      &.       do right part, then left part, then the inverse of the right part
    ,:         pad shorter one with zeros by making a table
XOR@           XOR the code points
        (3&u:) revert back code points -> string
```

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>60</s>\$\cdots\$ <s>55</s></sup> 54 bytes

Saved <s>2</s> 4 bytes thanks to [AZTECCO](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84844/aztecco)!!!

Saved <s>a</s> 2 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!

```c
#define f(a,b)for(;*a+*b;b+=!!*b)a+=putchar(*a^*b)!=*b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVHbToNAEH3vVywY43IxQq1ag9jUtokPJvYS0wepuguLkiAgYEps@u24s0tr2yc3GebsXM6ZZfzTd9@v66OAhVHCUIiJSbUwzbGjE0OnDjVcRdGpRgw3@y79D5JjnbzwgOLqtP4kUYI1tGohfiCpo5IV5St5XiAXrdR7FsepqZpIIgCE@gEDEKdLlvukEBfoAm@3zzsXBwFwlg3fNx@ya@dQjjZy8zSPAwUql4/Th6Fs5IwArnsnSBy4iED36nJPqn83GI4AfBUNmEz@ZtpTZVXGqpIFja5X2aFXWYR7xr3FjXILoLun3yJDkM0mc8H3NB6PpoP@bLQrzsu7ksLqcGsDjYpkwto1KM6yTA4oR25G41tDOEpKFCUBq/hgltPAG1REPywN8WZu7awJiOdoDjIMUblZJZws51whVj31uPC4mPRewmGzY9GyMDc7kFfN2TKE@J@FW6mES4DA9v/ula5b6/oX)

Comment: @AZTECCO Unfortunately, that doesn't print the end of the longer string. But found a way that does - thanks! :-)

Comment: Oh my bad, you can save 1 more btw [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVHbToNAEH3vV2xJrNyMtFatQW1q28QHE3uJ6YNU3YVFSRAQMCU2fDvO7NLa9slNhjk7e@acWdY9eXfdqvJVajLN/aCpTk2d2WudGjprtZLvHIuqTl90phlAM5pNoDBMTLPL6pMGkaqRdYPAEgIk51n@Sp@X5IaslXsehrGpmEQiBJS5HkcQxiueujQTG@zC3O6cdc8PCpisNn7fXDwt7UM7Vtst4jT0mshcPc4eRrIRFBFc9Y@JWLgRhd7lxZ7V4G44GiP4ymownf7NtOfKi4QXOfdqX6do@05hUcgcsgXBIDzs7uu3xBBi8@lC6D1NJuPZcDAf75oDvSclrC5EB2UUIg@s3UBykiRyQDlyPZofp0QNopwEkccLGMyya3hNsuCHx766mVs7rQviOppNDEMwN0@JK0lBy1cVRznKHDCT2YkA1m8sWpbm5g3kVrO3Cr76T@LWKgILNNj@3z1q2SirXw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: And one more using macros [Try it o](https://tio.run/##jVHfT4MwEH7fX1ExYqEY2Zw6g7rMbYkPJu5HzB5kagtFSRAQMCMu@9ux17K57ckm1/uud/d9B@edvHteVR36PAhjjgJMLWYESYYdkxKTiVvXKSGWyXSdEWKk34X3QTNs0heTGU71ScMYG2jZQOJAxkQFz4tX@jxHN2ip3fMoSizNQgoBoMzzOYAoWfDMo7kMoAt8s3XWPt97AGc34X7zILty9uVYLTdLssg/gMrF4@RhoBoFI4Cr7jGSBwL50Lm82JHq3fUHQwBfeQ3G47@ZdlR5mfKy4H6t65bNwC1tKjwX3hbGhPnQ3TVvEZFk0/FM8j2NRsNJvzcdbouL8o6isNvCWkCjIZWwtw2K0zRVA6qR69HE3hAO4wKFsc9LMZjt1PAa5eEPTwK8nts4rR/k5xgOIkRWrlcJJ80EV4A1VzvKXSGmvBsLWO9Ytsyt9Q5UaDgbhgD/s3AjFQsJENj8353SVWNV/QI "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @AZTECCO Nice one - thanks! :-)

Comment: @ceilingcat Of course, nice one - thanks! :D

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) for a byte!

```
Ç0ζε`^ç
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cLvBuW3ntibEHV7@/3@0UkKysYmpko5SYKBSLAA)

#### Commented

```
	 implicit input          ["QQ", "`c345"]

Ç        convert to charcodes    [[96, 99, 51, 52, 53], [81, 81]]
  ζ      Zip with filler ...     [[96, 81], [99, 81], [51, "0"], [52, "0"], [53, "0"]]
 0       ... zero
   ε     Map ...                   [96, 81]
    `      Dump on stack           96, 81
     ^     XOR                     49
      ç    Convert to character    "1"

         implicit output         ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

Comment: [7 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cLvBuW3ntibEHV7@/3@0UkKysYmpko5SYKBSLAA) by taking the input as a pair of strings.

Answer (score 4):

## Excel, <s>158 153</s> 108 bytes

(Not counting closing parens)

### Compatibility Notes:

- Minimum version: `CONCAT()` came to be in later versions of [Excel 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/concatenate-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d) (from `CONCATENATE()`).

### The Formulae

- Inputs: `A1`, `B1`
- A2: `=MIN(LEN(A1:B1))`, 14
- B2: `=LEN(A1)-LEN(B1)`, 15

Code (124):

```
=CONCAT(CHAR(BITXOR(CODE(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(A2),1)),CODE(MID(B1,SEQUENCE(A2),1)))))&RIGHT(IF(B2>0,A1,B1),ABS(B2))
```

One unfortunate caveat is that Excel ignores non-printable characters in cells. Alternatively, if you'd rather I use "\xXX" characters, I have this:

```
=CONCAT("\x"&DEC2HEX(BITXOR(CODE(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(A2),1)),CODE(MID(B1,SEQUENCE(A2),1))),2))&RIGHT(IF(B2>0,A1,B1),ABS(B2))
```

at 118 bytes. This just prints all XOR'ed characters as "\xXX" characters and leaves the trailing characters alone. Eg: `Hello!` and `World!!` produce `\x3F\x2A\x3E\x20\x2B\x00!`

#### How it Works:

1. The `SEQUENCE(A2)` effectively creates a range of (1..A2). As far as I can tell, I cannot re-use this by caching it in a cell, which is why I had to use it twice.
2. Each item is then converted to numbers with `CODE()` and `BITXOR()`ed against each other.
3. The `CHAR()` converts this to a character, while `DEC2HEX(...,2)` converts it to a 2 width 0-padded hex number.
4. `CONCAT()` puts the array together
5. `RIGHT(...)` tacks on the trailing characters of the longer string.

Comment: May want to throw in that as this uses the `BitXOr` function, this is limited to Excel 2013 and later

Comment: @TaylorScott True, but I think the minimum compatibility is actually 2019, because `CONCATENATE()` was changed to `CONCAT()`

Comment: You're right - `Concat()` is the limiting function here, but I think it limits to Office v `16.0.xx` which would include Office 2016, 2019 and 365. At least I can confirm that it is functional in up-to date versions of Excel 2016 on Win 10

Comment: Yup, you're right. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/concatenate-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 71 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b:chr(ord(a[0])^ord(b[0]))+f(a[1:],b[1:])if a and b else a+b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLfT8IwEMef3V9RfbkWCNkQFUgmUSHxwUQmMTww1HbrwpKyznZR/OuxN6ZRtMn1Luvnez/alR/VWheng9Lsdlmo@EaknPCOGCVrQ7VJKV/6K/aEkcCItTP3KRitOgJ3lmfE8UVKBJHKSsLbYpdvSm0qYqRnQwMAS7iVSukOdAgstFHpMazI94J4G2Tx1ufOS@d9Z8JZCl4jRN37/cPd5KfMCcetS9JGiosklUj5Qe@0f0BF82gRIaX0uzQJt0ieDMewPz@paXiczaYPN1fzKZKVtBWm@52pyVcfOghLnSE1HFycnx0Udf0P9jP5fWc9nAvIc6GrZxIEgT/s/ShT@4NS0NzEtzUlkb@6vplM/wjKspzU3fsBQq/2H@hL66iXpGk/iv5S@9k893behlfJWprQyG6iN2WuJDVA42W3NY5XLLZtGgPGwNwOzOPWSvf4ShZ0OwobdTfLi5QrRS1jYRj4XqYN/mUkL8h25B2VJi8qmtEWlW9cUc4Qq0PB2O4T)

Comment: Nice solution! You can save 2 bytes by shortening the base case as `f=lambda a,b:a>''<b and chr(ord(a[0])^ord(b[0]))+f(a[1:],b[1:])or a+b`

Comment: `print(''.join(chr(ord(x)^ord(y))for x,y in zip(*input().split())))` would be only 66 bytes but unfortunately, making it work on strings of different lengths would require many more bytes; and it doesn't handle strings that contain whitespace :-(

Answer (score 3):

## Java 10, 109 bytes

```java
(a,b)->{int A=a.length,B=b.length;if(A<B){var t=a;a=b;b=t;A^=B^(B=A);}for(;A-->0;)a[A]^=A<B?b[A]:0;return a;}
```

I/O as arrays of characters.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##dVPfT9swEH7nr7j5ZY6aRmUb@1HPoAQmbdIAMR72UFrtnLiQLiSd7bRCVf/2YjveqsDIg33n77473@fLAlc4XBS/d3mFWsM5lvXmAKCsjVRzzCVcOBcgv0M1mUJOOwPjbhcRs/D2wC7aoClzuIAa@I5iLKLh8cbmgZRjUsn61tzFGRfBZOWcpp@zaLNCBYYjQy6Y4IalM57NaMbTiG3njaIsHQ6PRyzCSTqdcUs5EdYaj5iSplU1INvumKu/bEVl64drrJqygHvbDb02qqxv7d0x6loxUhtKvsqqamISA/nZqKp4RXwnPdSB68sf38/6GIq8kA4bHb55@66PVc1aqhy1xz@dvAb/9WPc6uD@qct15FkfP7w/@j/D709ZDkiz07MvfWR06IA/@hnwKw@Frq7Is9fzsvm4TjbAOBgiqHf9oI28T5rWJEsLmKqm5Fu9bI0eww0hAxyQGwJYF94Tzvtb/ymVksvWWOb4n0BhypTUbWWAQ53kFBPTnNrzVCl8oFEs@n5g2nRuPJtCLhtra0eWa3/cZQtzN@3C3WS52Sx5D2VlN2z7PJNyOggx1mQvSuCadQU7tWjHiLwWdJ/NdjpY2D8uaU1ZJb4DbdsJpH2cJUYvqWarhWfb7h4B)

**Explanation:**

```java
(a,b)->{             // Input as 2 character arrays as parameters as well as return-type
  int A=a.length,    //  `A`: the length of the first array `a`
      B=b.length;    //  `B`: the length of the second array `b`
  if(A<B){           //  If the length of `a` is smaller than `b`:
    var t=a;a=b;b=t; //   Swap the arrays `a` and `b`
    A^=B^(B=A);}     //   And also swap the lengths `A` and `B`
                     //  (`a`/`A` is now the largest array, and `b`/`B` the smallest)
  for(;A-->0;)       //  Loop index `A` in the range [`A`, 0):
    a[A]^=           //   Bitwise-XOR the `A`'th value in `a` with, and implicitly cast
                     //   from an integer codepoint to a character afterwards:
      A<B?           //    If index `A` is still within bounds for `b`:
       b[A]          //     XOR it with the `A`'th codepoint of `b`
      :              //    Else:
       0;            //     XOR it with 0 instead
  return a;}         //  Return the modified `a` as result
```

Note that we cannot use a currying lambda `a->b->` here, because we modify the inputs when swapping and they should be (effectively) final for lambdas.

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 48 bytes

```
: f ( s s -- s ) 0 pad-longest [ bitxor ] 2map ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc1PT8IwGAbwO5/icRflMDJQQMeBKBAgIRggxoMxoXTvkFjW0b4E/PSzgwqxh/759XnaVEjWpnhbjKfDGFvBX/gmk5GCpd2eMkn2uqvRkY2wyA0x/@RmkzE6lfE0htQJhWut0iJGiju4EsLQTVVEyEUSKp2tyTI@sNrwURt8orEVOTpFMCKldIDgXRuV3ASuX6tc8PA6n/S9iZVMyFlUb9w/eFP6QEYKW/pT9xan4e/YfejYn8pSs0w9tlvN/4nz8pdy8PzS6w@8RHUHO3uFpTw/NJudoPgF)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 66 bytes

```javascript
f=(a,b)=>b[a.length]?f(b,a):(B=Buffer)(a).map((c,i)=>c^B(b)[i])+''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9fT8IwFMXf@RSVl7ZSx0BQkAwissQYI38Ww8OYSdu1MFNXsk3BTz9b@oDhJif34f7OuTmf9IeWvMj21U2uU1HXMkCUMByMWUw9JfJttUsmEjFC8QOaBtNvKUWBEcXeF90jxElmWP4xRQzHWYJbENajuAFADJ@FUppAAuBaFyq9ggkBbtptADfHjtwcfWq2MNs3YkYpPHut9TBfvc7OTuedXI9By4GU8VRY0O90b3uX4DJarpcOVPogCk5LCzeHE@igpjFY8H2xCFdPj1Ho4EqUlQ39n3dOPV1PnP3Zt@BwcH/Xv/xu6gxcRb9n1LU1YSNpeFIXIeU7hGJKAEswCMaA67zUSnhKb9FLNH/zyqrI8m0mf5FEFsNmRvUf)

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 64 bytes

```
(a,b)=>(""/:a.zipAll(b,'\0','\0').map(x=>x._1^x._2))(_+_.toChar)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc1LT8MwDADge39FyKWJqEo7Nh6VOlQ2JA4gNDhw4FHcNB1FWVvSiI1N@@2lyXbKRA625c92WgYCujr74kyheyirjZPzAi36ioCctxFKpITflycly2r@RtHGcX5AoCJChOya3i7ReLwvUNwR8LK@QTA@icBfl00iBMk89zVwTaD@AhqyiscrPw3f@zCglKTHqa/qySdI2jX9JSUqUhB8y4WoPewh/FxLkR9hSh2btS4fHu@mFkLGcq4xCAenQwtFveSSQWsGLq9cZJ41pHirtFttfW5k9i7Oz0b/7Jh8sKcluZ5MbywKQi3f7aF8sP1ns5kWZ7vt/gA)

Run with

```
val f: ((String,String)=>String) = ...
println(f("01","qsCDE"))
...
```

Uses `zipAll` to zip the input strings with null bytes as padding, then XORs, finally using `foldLeft` shorthand `/:` to turn the whole thing back into a string.

Comment: [60 bytes?](https://tio.run/##dY3LTsMwEEX3/gqTTWwpqpJCeURyUGiRWIBQy4IFz0nilIDzwDa0tOq3hzjphkR4MTO@Z@5cFYOAuozeeazxDWTFFiU8xXkzEZBL5eNQSvh5uNMyK5ZPFG8R@gaB06/Cx53Igr8dsxpYELEARpusCoUgkWM/unZbaA4VWbOArEcv3nNTxlSX0zeQNP/o7LXJT4nyu6@j9wNlTSZRlGiKUNUoWhQkJdYVF6J0LAdb96UUyYFF6QAburpdXM96EKI44Qa63vjwqAdFueIyBtUunJ3buH29Jc2VNrwnm3OT1nd6cjz5x9P2gc@Q8GI6u@wh1zPkUw3Ja7wPm88NQbtd/Qs)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
cÈ^VcY
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=Y8heVmNZ&input=J2FiY2RlJwonMDEyMzQn)

```
cÈ^VcY     :Implicit input of strings U & V
c          :Map the charcodes in U
 È         :by passing each one at index Y through the following function
  ^        :  Bitwise XOR with
   VcY     :  Charcode at index Y in V
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 105 bytes

```lua
i,a,b=0,...print(a:gsub('.',load'i=i+1return a.char((...):byte()~(b:sub(i,i):byte()or 0))')..b:sub(#a+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJfa9swEH@2P4VGKJKJYqKs3VYPM7alsMFgdC97MIbJtrwKNCuRZMoo7VfP7qSY9mHGYP3@3J3vTmaWJ2N7achIamKsHJrmpLnkXb3lZVkenJ4Ck9VvP3eMlpSjhepar4VTYXYTkWV/Jx1jYC6q7m9QrHhiXYV@zfVCWUe2RUGLskzSSq5FUZzaNs9T@QOUj8UWwkgP53Ge@qDtlLRYJM@k98oFtnoA@EjqmgggN5sDY/TiSItqtO6PTGYQMBEkB5SraVjSB@WDB/ohz@gXZYzllBP60zozvKLvFxK5@@8/vu0jJbt@UEhtxe71ZaSMvVeulx7pprn@QEl82hZFrIH26MSQK0TX796@uaIv9fg9exB//PR5fxOJrUB89Av@1Z@T3N4CfoT5wGB1Lfgq9rMRfEcGCz3HHqXgRO6gySg2uuXLaS3axTRqh4PORpbsMLFI4XXAFaCwAwFmnGd6TH7ylFQS7tSUZ5lyzsIdoHs9jsqpKRCn/GxgwvEHp8MMx4sjvFX6PG8pVeUpL49ZcWtxVRmu9OuLaE7sHAD@N8M5FCJP/wA)

Taking two strings as arguments, this program calls per-character replace on one of them with essentially XOR function, then appends potentially missing fragment from second string (occurs if it is longer) and prints the result. TIO includes test suite.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 36 bytes

```php
[,$a,$b]=$argv;echo"$a\r$b\r",$a^$b;
```

Usage:

```
$ php -r '[,$a,$b]=$argv;echo"$a\r$b\r",$a^$b;' -- 'ABCDE' '123';echo
> pppDE
```

Explanation: first output string A, then carriage return `\r`, output string B, then another carriage return, then output the XOR (which truncates to the shorter of the 2 strings). Any characters of the longer string will have already been printed.

## PHP 7.4, 32 bytes

Using new arrow function syntax.

```php
fn($a,$b)=>($a|$b^$b)^($a^$a|$b)
```

Explanation:
In PHP binary operators, only the `|` will keep the longest string length and pad with `NUL`s. So we XOR string B with itself, leading to a string with NUL bytes of the same length as B, then OR that with A. This will pad A with NUL bytes and use the length of B, if B is longer than A. We do the same with B, and only *then* XOR.

Edits:

- arrow function variant
- missed the requirement of outputting the longest string

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
C÷꘍C
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=C%C3%B7%EA%98%8DC&inputs=%5B%22test%22%2C%20%22%22%5D&header=&footer=)

Because Vyxal auto-pads lol.

### Explained

```
C÷꘍C
C     # convert each character in each string to it's ordinal value
 ÷꘍   # bitwise xor each item
   C  # and convert the result back to characters
```

Alternatively, using Keg mode:

#### [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `K`, 1 byte

```
꘍
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=K&code=%EA%98%8D&inputs=%22lowercase%22%0A%229%3F%27%20%20%20%20%20%20%22&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 33 bytes

```
Ｆ⌈ＥθＬι«Ｆθ«≔ζη≔∧‹ιＬκ℅§κιζ»℅⁻｜ηζ＆ηζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU5BCoMwEDzrKxYvrpA@oHgotqeCYu/iIWiqSzXWJFax@PZUpbRz2Z1hZneKmqui4421904BJnyidmjX@cSeQSxkZWqkYAW8XWf39PvqRFpTJXFmUAfhn0eyxFhojfSLP4KAQapKkrzByFxlKSZ8MNjOMpi39OI6N0XS4GXtwwsjFCYkB41nMiNpkSqsNyuDr7C92ZUVobtYm2V@041CFVwLn4F3PPkAXp7bw6v5AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as an array of two strings. Explanation:

```
Ｆ⌈ＥθＬι«
```

Loop over the longer length of the strings.

```
Ｆθ«
```

Loop over the strings.

```
≔ζη
```

Save the result of the previous loop, if any.

```
≔∧‹ιＬκ℅§κιζ
```

Get the ordinal at the current index, if that is less than the current string.

```
»℅⁻｜ηζ＆ηζ
```

Emulate bitwise XOR by subtracting the bitwise AND from the bitwise OR, then convert back to a character.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>80</s> <s>72</s> 69 bytes

```python
lambda*a:''.join(map(lambda x,y:chr(ord(x or'\0')^ord(y or'\0')),*a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBdb4IwFIbv/RWdXhxgZClMNzXZjBOTLVmiaBZvyFwFjC5IO6gRfj1rBZSJa3J6ctrnPV8s5Rsamtn6yckCslt5RCN9gLtvug2VHWFK/ogSPe27m0ihkackiEbgYFA/ZZSWkaprRFWz1lvI9hz9dyZ7Lr4bDRZtQ47WCrz6QUB10BEsaBR4N1CAKmqJG5zEWDsJJsL7wmNhK2EeXGSQCQ6T2bsFp1JFhoH2jG4rOFm5ni9xbJj37Rpuz@2FXcEDevAjl8RS0uwNCr5Z4h/T6Xg2Gs7HFQn3Yy4LwMXsheT4faZlFx2J97qPD51aP2LYbr4A3BZmyiUAWoaUL5FhGLhn1gsffb1wsb@T/W1CCocvI2t8RckYs6oTYkPSP/EFXeJ5mjP@5RYj2vY1PN9A9gs)

Uneven lengths are annoying...

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <del>86</del> 81 bytes

```powershell
$k=[char[]]($args[1]);([byte[]]([char[]]($args[0])|%{$_-bxor$k[$i++%$k.Length]}))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyXbNjo5I7EoOjZWQyWxKL042jBW01ol09bAWiM6qbIkFSSBpsIgVrNGtVolXjepIr9IJTtaJVNbW1UlW88nNS@9JCO2VlPz////ngqJuQppiSX/I/NLFRKLUhVKMjLzAA)

-5 bytes thanks to @mazzy

Comment: Welcome. You can use `$args[1]|% t*y` instead `[char[]]($args[1])`. The `% t*y` means "call the method `toCharArray`. And you can omit `$i=0`. See also [Tips for golfing in PowerShell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/191/tips-for-golfing-in-powershell)

Comment: Am I wrong or does this not work for two strings of unequal length?

Comment: @Thomas yep. You can see the two arguments are different length.

Comment: 1. You have to quote your input, if it contains spaces. You are actually processing `I` and `am` instead of `I am fat` and `You are thin`. 2. As you can see in your result, it contains only 1 byte instead of two bytes (`am` has two bytes), because you process up to the length of the first string. In conclusion, you just omit bytes if the first string is the shorter one and your code crashes if the second string is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/),  <s>44</s>  43 bytes

```c
x(o,r)char*o,*r;{*o|*r&&x(o+1,r+1,*o^=*r);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZFRS8MwEMff@ynOykaSVWkr@pLNJx98EARftw66LN0CNRlpqx1bP3tMurY4ayBw/H93/7tL2N2OMXMrJMurLYd5UW6Fut8/e78lLeTuWmPl8cCtZGqkAo3ZPtVEBUTTE1FnoqdTq8@iQNtL1HpBNKaNEbKEz1RI5IJU71gArhCIjb@WCYaTB/a02qbK0mX8@JTAAk5hQ6/IZkSco6DeJc4AOXe4WcADBs3LSkuIOmq3YYcjcv4BtI2jBNM/aNOh2KGW1V2Fg72WKQ1I2DFCCgLmrj7nEvWmcD6PZGcIs5nod@3nFQWTNq1tshQJxgN152A/oMyQv1rVkzCu/QD6PDrk8bzg/xZN2Ci/ucw/2Eq/X6l7rJB6jTGvPM@V@X7/eHv5AQ)

Uses recursion, note that to print strings containing the null byte one will have to manage the strings as arrays. (See the footer of the link for an example)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/),  <s>50</s>  49 bytes

```c
x(o,r)char*o,*r;{*o|*r&&x(o+!!*o,r+!!*r,*o^=*r);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZFRT4MwEMff@RQ3zJa2Q8Mw@tLNJx98MDHxdcMEusKaYLsUUBbgs2PLYHFiX3r5/@7@d9ey25Sx7kZIlpV7Duu82At1d3hyfktayPRaY8XpyI3UVUh5GrNDpInyiKY1UQ3Ri4XRl7OZ0bS9tEfUx4ZoTNtOyAI@IyGRDSKdMg9sORATf21DDLUD5vRaXCbRNnh4DGEDtd/SKxJPiHUU1DnHCSDrDrMN3GPQvCi1hNVAzU7seELW34O@8SrE9A@KBxRY1LNqqLBw1BKlAQkzhk9BwNrWZ1yi0RSaZiJbQ1guxbjrOK/ImTRpfZOtCDG@UHuO5huKBLm7XTX3g8r1YMyjlzye5fzfojmb5Lfn@S@20h1XGh7Lp07bdS88y1T3/fb@@vwD)

Slightly safer version (doesn't read past end of strings, requires enough memory to exist past them though - a la `strcpy`).

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/),  <s>61</s>  60 bytes

```c
x(b,o,r)char*b,*o,*r;{*o|*r&&x(b+1,o+!!*o,r+!!*r,*b=*r^*o);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZHBbsIwDIbvfQrDBErSbCpM2yWw0w47TJq0KxSpDSlE6hIUylYEffYubikaY/Ol1v859m9X3q6krG@0kfluqWCyLZba3q2fgp@S02Z1qcliv1FeqkuScssdlevEsZQzy5kTB2aPzA2HHoYjbsNez@sOP46zdMrcglkqqlqbAj4SbQgmiVtJDtgHmM8/ZzGFQwA@Gi3dZcls/PAYwxQOUSUuSPovkVcEZ2kRtHkGBOdCbwr3FJwqds7A6ET94nKzJziZQ2NpFFPxC6UnNEbUsBJlv0r7Dks6klkHRHszkQANE@ySK0O61nA8XsnYFsJQd7foXOutNL6sMTfTMaVnirHxf6zISH8@LwfRuOzz9hS6s4@h8q3689FAXtVXrf9zW9PvVjqdLBJBVdcvKs9t/fX2/vr8DQ)

As safe as any standard C function taking a buffer, at the cost of a few more bytes.

-1 byte from each thanks to ceilingcat!

Comment: You're relying on the first string storing as much memory as the second string in case the second string is longer than the first. That's not really playing fair. Certainly not how strings work in C.

Comment: You're also relying on memory past the end of the shorter string to be initialised to zero.

Comment: I agree it isn't the fairest, but given how strings are represented in C there isn't a much cleaner way to write this as a function. Your solution doesn't provide any means by which to access the new string, other than trapping the output stream. The only truly portable way would be to take 6 parameters: a, len(a), b, len(b), buffer, len(buffer). But defensive coding has never really been the goal of these submissions ;)

Comment: There are many ways to make your code cleaner. Not reading past the end of strings for starters. The point is that work is being done *outside* of your function to make it work. To change mine to return a string is trivial and certainly doesn't involve passing string lengths. Simply `malloc` a string buffer based on the maximum `strlen`s of the inputs and return that pointer after creating the result there.

Comment: same can be done in mine. it also still requires work outside of the function in terms of `free`. A solution would be something like this: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHNTsMwEITveYpREVL@oMC1tCcOHEBIXKFIjrtNLLl2ZTuUCvXZgxM7VYvqi8efvLPjNb@pOe@6K6G4bFeER@tWQt82i@QUGaHqc8bdfks9SqY5Xtkem9YxRxBq2zqEClvCkGuNslC0ixC7RvAGwkIrgl7DNX6Tq/5okU8T3jCD/EebNChWIogqw28Cv8LRNto4MiVyqVU9CEO2lW6WDLfEGqlvKUmlLMMCUVfZaNOvUIo52OzIorGHVYAHkLR0qaq6VBWtDiFGyORxKIrh/BAkIY3RTxNFVBT4mh8fWRT/PPupYnyup0I5bJhQaS@Yqfk4NK@/P5Zjg63/AbdOJ9f2U01K9EMeLtwvSwziYZlls7Mmd96/67pnklJ3u7f3l6c/ "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: You're still reading past the end of a string. Don't do that. It's making my eyes bleed! T_T

Comment: Wow, my bad :P wrote that out too quickly. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHLTsMwFET3@YpREVJeUGBb2hULFiAkthAkx71NLLl2ZTuECvXbgxMnVYvqTcZHnrmP8JuK8667EorLZk14tG4t9G29ik6REao6Z9ztd9SjaJ7ile2xbRxzBKF2jUNw2ByGXGOUhaJ2hGhrwWsIC60IegNX@49c91eLdB7xmhmkP9rEQbEcQZQJfiP4E6621saRyZFKrapBGLKNdItoeCU2iH1JSSpmCVYYdZlMMf0JVizBFkc2BntYBngASUuXXOUl1xh1CG2EnjwOprE5vwRJiKchTlsax8kyfC2PU2bZv9B@rZjm9VQohy0TKu4FMxWftub190cxFdj5X@A28ezafqpZjn7Lw4P7IscgHookWZwVufP5Xdc9k5S6a9/eX57@AA "C (gcc) – Try It Online") That one fixes the wrong name issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110832/discussion-between-lambdabeta-and-noodle9).

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ôM◙L╞@←
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=934d0a4cc6401b&i=123%0AABCDE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 11 bytes

```
ż§oc-¤nc¤vc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@ieQ8vzk3UPLclLPrSkLPn///9KOfnlqUXJicWpSv@VLO3VFRSUAA)

Unfortunately [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk) doesn't have a bitwise XOR command (that I could find), so we need to do:
arg1 OR (`v`) arg2 minus arg1 AND (`n`) arg2, costing an extra 5 bytes...

Answer (score 1):

## x86 machine code, 29 bytes

Machine code:

```
00000034: 31 d2 e3 08 8a 11 41 41 84 d2 e1 fe ac 84 c0 75  1.....AA.......u
00000044: 06 e3 09 89 ce 31 c9 30 d0 aa eb e4 c3           .....1.0.....
```

Commented assembly:

```c
        .intel_syntax noprefix
        .globl .strxor
        // Doesn't follow standard calling convention.
        // Input:
        //      EDI: Output buffer large enough for longest string
        //      ESI, ECX: Null terminated strings to XOR
        // Output:
        //      NON-null terminated string stored in EDI.
.strxor:
.Lloop:
        // Always clear EDX.
        xor     edx, edx
        // We mark the end of the shorter string
        // by setting ECX to null.
        jecxz   .Lskip_ecx
.Lno_skip_ecx:
        // Read a byte from ECX into DL.
        mov     dl, byte ptr [ecx]
        // Increment twice because LOOPZ decrements.
        inc     ecx
        inc     ecx
        // Was it '\0'?
        test    dl, dl
        // If so, set ECX to NULL by using LOOPZ in place.
        // CMOVZ ECX, EAX also works, but needs P6.
        // This works with i386 and is the same size.
.Lclear_ecx:
        loopz   .Lclear_ecx
.Lskip_ecx:
        // Load from ESI and autoincrement
        lods    al, byte ptr [esi]
        // Test for '\0'
        test    al, al
        jnz     .Lno_swap
.Lswap: // '\0' found
        // If ECX is null, we are at the end of both strings.
        jecxz   .Lend
        // Otherwise, we swap ESI and ECX, and then clear ECX.
        // Set ESI to ECX.
        mov     esi, ecx
        // And set ECX to NULL.
        xor     ecx, ecx
        // fallthrough
.Lno_swap:
        // XOR the two bytes together
        xor     al, dl
        // Store to EDI and autoincrement
        stos    byte ptr [edi], al
        // Loop unconditionally.
        jmp     .Lloop
.Lend:
        ret
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVdtb9s2EP6uX3HzVjgB/J6067xiRRZnWAA3bpt0NVpnGUXRNlOZ1EiqtoP99@yOki0r0vptAiyavFfePTyeQmaXj4@cOfgF5jIWnWt49QouJr8FkD8dqZyI7@xWObYBpRMj5nJTkBexDmPoWGc22uyXu10YaWFV08Fcx7Feg3VMRcxEwFkcS7UArtVXoZzUqnModqmS1A0PV/xzMbocwiR1SIQwnc@FgZiZhQChdLpYohVc0GohrENTBg1UVVxftuDifDqEqzSOwQmzkoo5EeUCFpyG6eT9oWBmserO1eSqrWq14KANzqQinztBHplh0BnHWiclVWfxmm0t8Fgwg9zTIhAo4UcRbVr0OpT6KGDFzBdwS9p9BHru/9qlNuhNze7DLVjhHDmH26ddkuuFsXvBNw@Uy7H9IpM7nKGzSt/tZiWf3wsWAUOdTsDc6JVXiRjRMBoXKlf6qx@juJWxJs7AZ9R1W841N2KFIAC3llxAKDhLrYDxZPL2E0Qip9pCr1Q8iwvffHONwsQsSAfNWa/5er/uCB@5X1Fc8mUOVrcoULsgXX0Yjyl2qaXIZT5hVpOYcVGC7PmbyR@fSArhdTYFFlsNa22@WNw7wlUJEVl4@6Ikc7OUNmOCtXRLkCcvXwCeEMBln022wpd8QEudsQdIOROEpSxne2JQ5K@UsbHGjGWpur70NljqtNzF/kAluokPK@fMylLObiiCdNoosJW4kiwr4nqvHrIq4eG0Zgn5iMOQNJEC1JSq6EkePKKsB2kL1gKYwZ87xHuoMWT5qa3DsSjrnKCoWUsrvDpyYB8KnzX6gyxqdxLPp6VcXRMmkB8xUSLtQI4haj1F3xmqfIKlmtPNNxXBOZZHtzRU1IJ92Er5xBLlY@HW2ueJ6tZC0BYrBlgF5tdUnfxORt/CAhYxj4UDHETytpRbjyydQKqwkkeSCjm6vj1IxyrJk09gDXxWio0Y4YIAdbTpCYr7xApOqqDRcWLjOqmynOppowUNtsH3s8ToRSidPXREbDjVDYpKiGD3aOQ6EjAdBZ0V40bD2w8358D3QklqlzTOeDWdDLNyWl0OcblfXfY5tEmVEJX4sUT6sbd52Su80MnOZNDB8KyCnbs3F9c3by4I4/0WvQd7Gb8RgGajWYn0yTzoFxHuMMvlAzRmpKQRDOopg0ZwclBWBCsg3Q@r67TbQXgYe4QektWCipjyKVBMfhWAV1tNDJMy4G0aHhCsrBqkZJyEVQH25OjwPAaZJlYQ7rFJoOd0XhwPvlyUeE9LByzS1LfgoYhThJAvU7gznTUfuNU9L95QO5tVBy3pDutwIcuAoYYog36lh1ob6cSRdREab2Uq0T60oX/8v8L20O9a4LIoqt9lDTopoiKWK0ndib/sepv5vIUVwF@l2MftCc2Zaj5VRcy7wxHk7eYddpPGBdlQ5C4/NND4XWDP2aKa8VGbOPqu8R8sxLGevB@PahhYyCNBDL3@4OS0hgG7WmE4s57pp9fNjFzDSOWIeGpIpPq5l3/544vn35D1Y608Uc9@PR9d1JB7faL@beups794bv3du0Y9nvr1eOrVowO/Gx4XnEN7dTKANt99UbR19k8H1NBA@2w3LXgxkU7iRGkEeyzDnINEaefB95CwLX59YB/gso8GusNWW1/uE2Fi5MjxhI2DVgm2Bo6Fscjbq3OsodsY@wfLWSKsv/IPRXRqPNCy7m6p42gHSYb92xo/WKgR6/qL5R9vENoJ1gbbPfr85@ehNze8naGG2@Ou9dP5UWM22zzrDaYYYW2iox/6x8fdhfjZdomvO1PdRTN4/Bc)

The code reads two null terminated strings from `esi` and `ecx`, and stores the NON null terminated string in `edi`.

The logic is probably easier to see in the equivalent C code.

```c
void strxor(char *dst, const char *src1, const char *src2)
{
    for (;;) {
        char x = '\0';
        if (src2 != NULL) {
            x = *src2++;
            if (x == '\0') { // eos
                src2 = NULL;
            }
        }
        char y = *src1++;
        if (y == '\0') {
            if (src2 == NULL) { // both eos
                return;
            } else { // src2 is longer
                src1 = src2;
                src2 = NULL;
            }
        }
        *dst++ = x ^ y;
    }
}
```

I don't null terminate because null bytes naturally show up in the output and it saves a byte.

I may also add a version with explicit lengths which accepts null bytes, but the solution would be significantly less elegant.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 14 bytes

```perl
sub f{pop^pop}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4NEkhrbogvyAOiGv/FydWKqRpKCUmJaekKukoGRgaGZsoaVpzQcVLUotLgMIIEfWc/PLUouTE4lR1HQUlS3t1BTAAKvj/L7@gJDM/r/i/rq@pnoGhAQA)

Answer (score 0):

## Scala 3, <s>30</s> 29 bytes

```
a=>b=>a zipAll(b,0,0)map(_^_)
```

[Try it online](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/0szOKel0TIqe2F3tK8I03g)

## Scala 2, <s>41</s> <s>39</s> 38 bytes

Used infix notation to turn `.map` into just `map`

```
a=>b=>a zipAll(b,0,0)map(a=>a._1^a._2)
```

Inputs and output are lists of integers

[Try it online](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/5uxNZJaHQS6GjkNQ7RPctg)